# Why CALayer and CAShapeLayer behaving differently

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer, cashapelayer

First I created the `CAShapeLayer` for masking the `UIView` at the bottom with height of 10px like this:

```
CAShapeLayer *mask = [[CAShapeLayer alloc]init];
CGRect maskRect = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-10, self.view.frame.size.width, 10.0);
CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithRect(maskRect, NULL);
mask.path = path;
CGPathRelease(path);
mask.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);
self.view.layer.mask = mask;
```

After commenting the above code I created a `CALayer` for masking the `UIView` at the bottom with height of 10px like this:

```
CALayer *mask = [CALayer layer];
mask.contents = (id)[[self getImg]CGImage];
mask.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-5, self.view.frame.size.width, 10.0);
mask.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);
self.view.layer.mask = mask;
```

***Question 1:***

To perfectly touch the bottom not a pixel above or below, for `CAShapeLayer` the `CGRect` I defined is

```
CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-10, self.view.frame.size.width, 10.0);
```

and for `CALayer` the `CGRect` I defined is

```
CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-5, self.view.frame.size.width, 10.0);
```

why -10 for `CAShapeLayer` and why -5 for `CALayer` ?

---

The animation code and its effects on `CAShapeLayer` and `CALayer`:

```
CGRect oldBounds = mask.bounds;
    CGRect newBounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        CABasicAnimation* revealAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds"];
        revealAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:oldBounds];
        revealAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:newBounds];
        revealAnimation.duration = 0.5;
        [mask addAnimation:revealAnimation forKey:@"revealAnimation"];
    }];
    // Update the bounds so the layer doesn't snap back when the animation completes.
    mask.bounds = newBounds;
```

Effect on `CAShapeLayer` the position is changed but no effect on hight like this:

[image]

Effect on `CALayer` which worked perfectly and the result I wanted:

[image]

***Question 2:***
Why `CAShapeLayer` changed the position not the height?

I don't know why but I am having a feeling like `CALayer` animation is not going smooth?

***Question 3:***

The `[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{ ...` block do not have any effect on animation, why?

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1: 
Not sure why it is 5 and 10 for `CAShapeLayer` and `CALayer`, need to debug closely, but maybe problem is in adjusting `anchorPoint` or because you use `path` of shape layer

Answer 2: 
About effect on `CAShapeLayer`: this is because you assigned `CGPath` to it, and changed shape layer frame, but not path. So you need to set new `path` property with correct coordinates. Something like this:

```
CGRect maskRect =  CGRect newBounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithRect(maskRect, NULL);
mask.path = path;
CGPathRelease(path);
```

Answer 3:

`CABasicAnimation` is class, which will do all animation, and you don't need to use it in `UIView animateWithDuration` block.

This code should work as expected:

```
CABasicAnimation* revealAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds"];
revealAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:oldBounds];
revealAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:newBounds];
revealAnimation.duration = 0.5;
[mask addAnimation:revealAnimation forKey:@"revealAnimation"];
```